# How do you express: Hello Jack and Jill

Tags: grammar

I want to start an email with:

> Hello Jack and Jill

I'm thinking something like:

> Jack , Jill 你们好。

I feel there is something wrong with:

> Jack 和 Jill 你们好。

What is the best way to express this?

Answer (score 2):

"Jack 和 Jill 你们好." is fine when addressing your contemporary. But you can consider the following:

Assume they are your friends, then add "Dear" in the front:

- **親愛的**Jack 和 Jill 你们好.

If they are your elders, then add "Respected & Beloved":

- **敬愛的**Jack 和 Jill 你们好.

For your bosses, business associates, add "Respected/Regarded":

- **敬重的/尊敬的**Jack 和 Jill 你们好.

To whom you have a very close relationship, you can say:

- **摯愛的** (Deeply Beloved) Jack 和 Jill 你们好.

Answer (score 1):

Jack and Jill went up the hill,
To fetch a pail of water,
Jill came down with half a crown,
It wasn't for the water.

你好杰克，你好吉尔，

```
山顶上怎么样？
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer of r13 (+1). What I would suggest is to:

1. Use a **formal address** (if needed) using titles such as 先生, 女士, 老师, 大夫, etc. after each name.
2. Use **与** instead of 和.

> Jack**先生与**Jill**女士**

3. Format the email properly adding **punctuation and spacing**. Example:

> Jack先生与Jill女士：
>       你们好！